# How to convert a string to a datetime format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a string in the following format '20-DEC-2013' to a datetime format.

The only function I know is the STR_TO_DATE but it is not working or I am doing something incorrectly.

here is what I have done but it is not working. it is returning NULL

```
select STR_TO_DATE('20-DEC-2013', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS date;
select select STR_TO_DATE('7/14/2013', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS date;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE()` expects the format of the date as the second parameter:

```
select CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE('20-DEC-2013', '%d-%b-%Y'), ' 00:00:00') AS date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28308)

Comment: this is not working. Can you please help me correct it CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE('7/14/2013', '%d-%b-%Y'), ' 00:00:00') AS date

Comment: `CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE('7/14/2013', '%c/%e/%Y'), ' 00:00:00') AS date`. See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for date formatting info.

Comment: Got it. So the second parameter for the STR_TO_DATE is the actual format of the giving string not the output.  Thanks :)